# Headphones not working in Kubuntu 18.04, inbuilt speakers are working

Tags: sound, headphones

I'm getting no audio from headphones, but inbuilt speakers are working.

I'm using Kubuntu 18.04.

Settings in alsamixer are as follows:

[image: alsamixer_screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to **System Settings > Multimedia > Audio & Video > Device Preference**

Make sure you set your headphones to a higher preference than inbuilt speakers for Music, Video, and whatever other audio categories you're using your headphones for.

Comment: Actually this have helped. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Using side arrow keys in keyboard, select the `Headphone` tab in **Alsamixer** and press `M` button in keyboard. This will unmute headphone. Then it will show `OO` instead of `MM` (which means headphone is in mute mode)

Comment: not working :-(

Comment: Unmute the `Master` & `Speaker` also

Comment: tried that too bro... still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have lost the plug-and-play feature where the headphones simply just worked upon sticking them in the jack (or had a drop down/toggle menu at the top-right corner of the screen) when I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04.

I've found that in **Settings > Sound > Output** I have two options. If I click on *Speakers - Built-in Audio* it uses the computer's speakers, but if I click on/test *Digital Output (S/PDIF) - Built-in Audio*, my headphones work.